# nothing found even tho pages exist - after wordpress update

Tags: database, wordpress, permalinks, corruption

My Wordpress site stopped working properly after I updated wordpress. I have several custom post types that work fine, but for some reason linking or viewing core pages does not work. I feel like this has to do with permalink but I have disabled and reset and still nothing. I originally had no "posts" on my site. With testing I created a post. Now any time I try to view any core page or go to "mysite.com/admin" it directs to the test post I created.

Not sure how to fix this. Could it be Database Corruption?

Any Tips on fixing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an update - I have tried using the base themes 2010-2015 and still nothing. I disabled all plugins as well.